# Berkeley DB works slowly after I hooked the recv function of mongoose

Tags: c, mongoose, berkeley-db, ld-preload

what I am doing is a little bit tricky. I tried to hook the `recv` function of mongoose using `LD_PRELOAD`. After mongoose receives a request, it will first of all store this request into Berkeley DB and then proceed.
 However, I found that the storing speed of Berkeley DB is much slower than usual. Storing the same size of contents, an independent program only takes 1000 nanoseconds, but the hooked mongoose can take up to 20 milliseconds. I totally have no idea how this could happen. Any help would be appreciated.

```
typedef uint32_t req_id_t;
typedef uint32_t view_id_t;

typedef struct view_stamp_t{
    view_id_t view_id;
    req_id_t req_id;
}view_stamp;

typedef struct db_t{
    DB* bdb_ptr;
}db;

#define BILLION 1000000000L

const char* db_dir="./.db";

uint64_t vstol(view_stamp vs){
    uint64_t result = ((uint64_t)vs.req_id)&0xFFFFFFFFl;
    uint64_t temp = (uint64_t)vs.view_id&0xFFFFFFFFl;
    result += temp<<32;
    return result;
};

void mk_path(char* dest,const char* prefix,const char* db_name){
    memcpy(dest,prefix,strlen(prefix));
    dest[strlen(prefix)] = '/';
    memcpy(dest+strlen(prefix)+1,db_name,strlen(db_name));
    dest[strlen(prefix)+strlen(db_name)+1] = '\0';
    return;
}

db* initialize_db(const char* db_name,uint32_t flag)
{
    db* db_ptr=NULL;
    DB* b_db;
    DB_ENV* dbenv;
    int ret;
    char* full_path = NULL;

    if((ret=mkdir(db_dir,S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH))!=0){
        if(errno!=EEXIST){
            goto db_init_return;
        }
    }

    full_path = (char*)malloc(strlen(db_dir) + strlen(db_name)+2);
    mk_path(full_path,db_dir,db_name);

    if ((ret = db_env_create(&dbenv,0)) != 0) {
        dbenv->err(dbenv, ret, "Environment Created: %s", db_dir);
        goto db_init_return;
    }
    if ((ret = dbenv->open(dbenv,db_dir,DB_CREATE|DB_INIT_CDB|DB_INIT_MPOOL|DB_THREAD, 0)) != 0) {
        goto db_init_return;
    }
    /* Initialize the DB handle */
    if((ret = db_create(&b_db,dbenv,flag))!=0){
        goto db_init_return;
    }

    if((ret = b_db->open(b_db,NULL,db_name,NULL,DB_BTREE,DB_THREAD|DB_CREATE,0))!=0){
        goto db_init_return;
    }
    db_ptr = (db*)(malloc(sizeof(db)));
    db_ptr->bdb_ptr = b_db;

db_init_return:
    if(full_path!=NULL){
        free(full_path);
    }
    return db_ptr;
}

int store_record(db* db_p, size_t key_size, void* key_data, size_t data_size, void* data){
    int ret = 1;
    if((NULL == db_p)||(NULL == db_p->bdb_ptr)){
        if(db_p == NULL){
          printf("DB store_record : db_p is null.\n");
        } else{
          printf("DB store_recor : db_p->bdb_ptr is null.\n");
        }
        goto db_store_return;
    }
    DB* b_db = db_p->bdb_ptr;
    DBT key,db_data;
    memset(&key, 0, sizeof(key));
    memset(&db_data, 0, sizeof(db_data));
    key.data = key_data;
    key.size = key_size;
    db_data.data = data;
    db_data.size = data_size;

    struct timespec start, end;
    uint64_t diff;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

    if ((ret = b_db->put(b_db,NULL,&key,&db_data,0)) == 0){
    }
    else{
        printf("DB : %s.\n", db_strerror(ret));
    }

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    diff = BILLION * (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
    printf("elapsed time = %llu nanoseconds\n", (long long unsigned int) diff);

db_store_return:
    return ret;
}

int i = 1;

view_stamp vs;
db* db_ptr;

ssize_t recv(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags)
{
  if (i == 1)
  {
      db_ptr = initialize_db("node_test",0);
      vs.view_id = 0;
      vs.req_id = 0;
  }
  i = 0;
  typedef ssize_t (*orig_recv_type)(int, void *, size_t, int);
  orig_recv_type orig_recv;
  orig_recv = (orig_recv_type) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "recv");
  ssize_t ret = orig_recv(sockfd, buf, len, flags);

  vs.req_id++;
  uint64_t record_no = vstol(vs);
  store_record(db_ptr, sizeof(record_no), &record_no, ret, buf);

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks for your reply. The code is there.

Comment: If your "independent program only takes 1000 nanoseconds", then the results may not have actually been committed to disk.  There might be something wrong with the other program!  As with all these cases, please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.